# Saving Spreadsheet to Folder in Google Sheets API (Python)

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am working with the Google Sheets API in Python but am having trouble finding out how to save a newly created Spreadsheet to a specific folder. As of now all it does is populate my drive without the ability to indicate an end location. Any idea how to do this in Python?

I have found help with other languages but the python documentation is much different. Any insight would be great...

Comment: Unfortunately, new Spreadsheet cannot be directly created in the specific folder using Sheets API. And also, the Spreadsheet cannot be moved to the specific folder using Sheets API. As a workaround, how about using Drive API? For example, when new Spreadsheet is directly created to the specific folder, you can use the method of Files: create. And when the existing Spreadsheet is moved to the specific folder, you can use the method of Files: update. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/ If these were not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: thanks ill look into it. does that mean ill have to move from sheets api to drive api?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Only when the new Spreadsheet is created or the existing Spreadsheet is moved to the specific folder, you are required to use Drive API.